# Shopify: Themekit auto processing templates/customers after theme watch

Tags: shopify

I'm always get this error when using Shopify theme kit 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN6bn.png)

Sometime it also process to upload all file in project to server. This cause conflict with other people working on it and make they lost their code.

I've tried to search the error but cant find the solution for it.
Does anyone else have the same problem as mine?

Please give me some advice,
thanks :)

Comment: Can you confirm that you don't have additional folders in the customers folder or in the asset folder?

Comment: @drip Yes, i just create new theme base from debut. I think there're conflict between VS Code and Theme kit. I also have error that sometime themekit process a file to server when i just open the file or move the cursor on file, not change any line of code on it. Maybe VS Code change something of file that ThemeKit recognize it's an update and process it.